# how to open the results of a DNN model from localhost of a remote server in local browser

Tags: server, ssh, google-chrome, browser, remote-login

I run a deep learning model on a remote cluster and I use `visdom` library for the visualization of the results. I use this command line to connect to the server:

```
ssh -L 8097:localhost:8097 username@vremote.serveraddress
```

after running my code, I got this messsage:

```
Job 556789 is allocated resource
It's Alive!
You can navigate to http://gpu168:8097/
```

when I use this link in my chrome browser, I am not able to see the results and I get this message

```
This site can’t be reached gpu168’s server IP address could not be found.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I appreciate it if someone can suggest how I fix this problem.

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:8097/`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your setup entirely, but you're configuring `localhost:8097` on your local machine to be forwarded to `localhost:8097` on your remote machine (`vremote.serveraddress`). Is it that your remote machine is serving the visualization on localhost? If so, you should connect to `localhost:8097` on your local machine

Comment: @steeldriver I get this error message in my chrome-browser (mac) `This site can’t be reachedThe connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
`

Comment: @steeldriver I also got this message in my terminal `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`

Comment: Have you verified that there's indeed something listening on localhost:8097 on the remote machine?

Comment: @Dalek there's some additional information here [Setup Visdom on Remote Server](https://gist.github.com/amoudgl/011ed6273547c9312d4f834416ab1d0c) that suggests unsetting any proxy settings as well

Comment: @steeldriver Do you mean by using `no_proxy=localhost` before `python script.py`?

Comment: @frippe How can I test that my machine is listening to the localhost of the remote machine?

Comment: On the remote machine, run `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8097` to find out if there's something listening

Comment: @frippe I don't have sudo permission on the remote machine.

Comment: You don't need to, just drop sudo. The difference is that without sudo, not all processes may be shown

Comment: @frippe I got this message `(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)`

Comment: That's normal, but more importantly, if that's all output, there's nothing listening